# seaborn FacetGrid: How to leave proper space on top for suptitle

Tags: python, page-title, seaborn

Could someone show me how to leave extra space on top of a FacetGrid? I try to put a super title to the top of a FacetGrid plot but end up with the super-title overlapping with the subplot titles due to very limited margin on top in the default setting.

Thanks

Answer (score 40):

Use the Figure method `subplots_adjust` to add space to the top of the plot:

```
g = sns.lmplot("x", "y", col="c", data=df)
g.figure.suptitle("Title of the plot", size=16)
g.figure.subplots_adjust(top=.9)
```

Answer (score 10):

`.suptitle(...)` is a [matplotlib figure function](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.suptitle). It has `x` and `y` arguments, with `y=0.98` as the default. You can adjsut it to be a bit higher, instead of moving the subplots (in some cases you may not have enough freedom there).

```
g.fig.suptitle("My super title", y=1.05)
```

Answer (score 1):

Although my answer is not for the **suptitle**, it helps when you need to increase space for **each** facet's title:

```
g.set_titles(pad=15)
```